# Android email encryption

Tags: encryption, email, android

Is there a reliable (in terms of security), open-source application for handling (send/receive + en-/decrypt) encrypted emails on Android? Something like [TextSecure](https://whispersystems.org/) for emails.

I just found a command line implementation of GPG on [f-droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=encrypt&fdid=info.guardianproject.gpg) but this is really impractical in everyday use.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty android applications in the market.

I am using K9 with APG (Android Privacy Guard) and I am very pleased.

K-9 Mail is a free and open source email client for Android devices, that integrates seamlessly with Android Privacy Guard.

Android Privacy Guard (APG) is a free and open source application that lets you encrypt, decrypt and sign files, messages or emails using Public Key Encryption (like OpenPGP) or encrypt/decrypt files or messages with symmetric encryption, securing them with a password.

The use of these two tools allows for easy encrypting and decrypting of email messages.

Comment: I just read that APG is no longer maintained and its successor OpenKeychain is somewhat incomplete. I'll look at the APG source tho.